# how to change the volume of a clip when it is playing

Tags: java, audio

OK so i am using this example to load sound in my program

```
public static void playSound(String url,int Vol){
    try {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(SoundsEngine.class.getResource("/Resources/Sounds/"+url+".wav"));
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        FloatControl gainControl = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        gainControl.setValue(Vol);
        clip.start();
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

i was wandering if there were any ways that i could change the volume without stopping the loop??
Im not sure i have done this correctly its the first time i am working with Sounds in java, i tried just running the playSound() again with the Vol integer different but it ended up just opening more files, just for your information, i am using a JSlider to change the volume, thanks in advance any help is appreciated